# What is the point of se_blank.html?

Tags: experience-manager

When setting up Experience manager, we have to ensure that the web application serves a page called se_blank.html.

What purpose does this serve? If I fail to arrange for se_blank.html to be found, and just accept that I'll get 404 return statuses, what will the functional effect be on the working of Experience Manager?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a frame that's used to clear cookies set by Experience Manager. `se_blank.html` is set as the source of that frame.

If it returns a 404, everything *should* still work, but it's important that the response comes from the correct domain so that Experience Manager has access to the right cookies.

Credit should go to Peter Kjaer for the explanation on an internal SDL discussion list!

Answer (score 7):

The only reason for you to make `se_blank.html` available is  so you don't get the 404 errors which might cloud your error log. XPM will work fine either way.

In DXA we just added a special route for this page, see https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Site/Global.asax.cs#L26, quite a simple thing to do so you never have to worry about it anymore.