# XPM tag: ItemNotFoundException: Unable to find page by url

Tags: experience-manager, dd4t

I have an issue with XPM tag [Issue with <xpm:init> tag](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14084/issue-with-xpminit-tag)? and I by pass the issue by hardcode below to my page template just to test it out.

[image]

The SDL Tridion button now show up and I could see my contents in Tridion edit mode but I could not edit it at all. There is an error show up in dd4t log

2016-03-07 10:24:54,622 DEBUG AbstractPageController - >> GET page /se_blank.html with dispatcher type REQUEST
2016-03-07 10:24:54,623 DEBUG UrlPublicationResolver - Using cd_dynamic_conf.xml to determine publication Id
2016-03-07 10:24:54,629 DEBUG PageFactoryImpl - Enter findPageByUrl with url: /se_blank.html and publicationId: 528
2016-03-07 10:24:54,735 TRACE AbstractPageController - Unable to find page by url '/se_blank.html' and publication '528'.
org.dd4t.core.exceptions.ItemNotFoundException: Unable to find page by url '/se_blank.html' and publication '528'.
    at org.dd4t.providers.impl.BrokerPageProvider.getPageMetaByURL(BrokerPageProvider.java:189) ~[dd4t-providers-2.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.providers.impl.BrokerPageProvider.getPageByURL(BrokerPageProvider.java:82) ~[dd4t-providers-2.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.core.factories.impl.PageFactoryImpl.findPageByUrl(PageFactoryImpl.java:137) ~[dd4t-core-2.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.dd4t.mvc.controllers.AbstractPageController.showPage(AbstractPageController.java:98) ~[dd4t-mvc-support-2.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.se.tridion.dd4t.controllers.PageController.showPage(PageController.java:48) [dd4t-1.jar:na]

Does anyone see this kind of errors before? I am using DD4T version 2.0.2

Thanks for your help

Comment: I remember this issue indeed. I'll have a look.

Comment: check http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13353/what-is-the-point-of-se-blank-html  may help

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the replied. We found our issue.

The "PageTemplateID": "tcm:527-157698-128" was missing comma after that. This should not be an issue if we use xpm:int tag.

Thanks again.